Optimal tickmark placement

You play a game as follows:
Imagine a gold bar with tickmarks like a number line from $0$ to $1$. Three players will put a line at different marks on the gold bar. They will each get a part of the gold bar that is nearest to their marker. For example, if players 1, 2, 3 select $0.3$, $0.4$ and $0.6$, respectively, then players would get $[0, 0.35], [0.35, 0.5], [0.5, 1],$ respectively.
If player 1 places at $0.1$, and it is your turn (player 2). Where is the optimal marker to place?

I believe the answer to this would be $0.55$, because it covers the widest spread of numbers. Is this the correct answer?

You need to think about how player three will respond to your move. If you choose $0.55$, then player three will choose $0.55+\epsilon$, leaving you with $0.225+\frac{\epsilon}2$. You need to think, for every place $x$, where would player three place their mark if I placed my mark at $x$, and therefore what is my payoff from placing at $x$. Finally, maximize this payoff as a function of $x$.

It should be clear that player 2 shouldn't place $x<0.1$ by elimination of dominated strategies. Now if P2 place it somewhere $x$, their expectation if player 3 places at $y$ is (P3 has two actions: right of $x$ or left but $>0.1$):
$$(y-0.1)/2; \quad y>x$$
or $$1-(x+y)/2; \quad x>y$$
Regardless what player 3 plays, player 2 expects at least $(x-0.1)/2$ if player 3 chooses right ($y>x$) and at least $(1-x)$ if P3 chooses left. P2 will be really indifferent if $(x-0.1)/2=1-x$ or equivalently $x=0.7$. Payoff is at least $0.3$ where $0.3$ is attained assuming P3 is rational.

Thank you for your answer! It seems there are some typos in your response. The conditions for both expectation equations you wrote are the same ($y > x$). Could you also elaborate a bit more on these equations? I am new to this, and I find it quite hard to follow your solution.

@ShsTht Yes sure, I provided a sketch of the solution instead of a detailed walkthrough and I fixed that typo. The equations I got were a direct application of the rules of the game (whoever is close to the point claims it). But the real idea is in the equilibrium criterion; that is the expected return is equal regardless of what P3 will play. Note: I gather that you're probably preparing for Quant interviews, it would be beneficial to the community if you shared references and resources

Thank you! One of my acquaintances was asked this question in an interview. Unfortunately, I don’t have a source or reference for it.

While I suspect that the answer that whoever wrote the question expects is the one given by sfedo there is actually a better strategy by players 2 and 3.
We will assume players all place non-equal marks, know what all earlier players placed and play rationally, additionally we will assume that player 1 is not actually a player to simplify the calculations (player 1 is not playing rationally and I don't want to complicate things more than needed by discussing how things work if player 1 is involved)
Let us first note that if player 2 plays anywhere to the left of 0.1 then they can get at most 0.1, this is much worse than what they will get if they for example play at 0.7 so we can ignore this case.
Now suppose player 2 plays at some point to the right of 0.1 but less than 0.7, then player 3 always does best by playing slightly to the right of player 2, and so player 2 should get around $\frac{x-0.1}{2}$ if they play at $x$, this is maximised when $x$ is close to $0.7$ and so player 2 will get at most $0.3$ this way.
Now suppose that player 2 plays at some value that is at least $0.7$, then player 3 does best by playing at some point between player 1 and player 2, but notice that in fact it does not affect player 3's payout where they play as they will always get $\frac{y+x}{2}-\frac{y+0.1}{2}=\frac{x-0.1}{2}$ when player 2 plays at $x$ and player 3 plays at $y$. This allows player 3 to use an interesting strategy.
Player 3 will act as follows, as long as player 2 plays above $0.7$ but below $1$, player 3 plays some value slightly below player 2, this makes player 2 have payout around $1-x$ if they play at $x$, this is always at most slightly above $0.3$. If on the other hand player $2$ plays at $1$ then player 3 will play at some point slightly above $0.1$, this makes player 2 have payout around $0.45$ which is much better than anything else they can get.
Using this we can see that player 2 should play at $1$ and player 3 should play at $0.1+\epsilon$ for some very small $\epsilon>0$, this gives payouts of $0.1+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$,$0.45-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $0.45$ for players 1, 2 and 3.
By checking carefully we can see this is in fact the optimal way for players 2 and 3 to play and so as long as both players are rational player 3 does not actually need to declare that they will be using this strategy for player 2 to cooperate.
Hopefully all of this is correct, please let me know if you see any mistakes.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
